# Excluding Test Projects from Fortify Scan in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, fortify

I am submitting a Fortify scan through an ADO Pipeline, using the Fortify Static Code Analyzer Assessment plugin.  The pipeline is building the solution first, then scanning it.  There are several unit test projects in my solution that I would like to exclude, but none of the solutions I've seen suggested seem to work.  Is it because I cannot use a relative path?  These are the options I've tried in the Additional Fortify SCA build options:

```
-exclude "**/UnitTests/**/*"
-exclude "**/UnitTests/*"
-exclude "*/UnitTests/*.*"
-exclude "**\UnitTests\*.*"
```

UnitTests is the name of the project in the .Net solution.  And all files to exclude are directly under a folder by that name.

Comment: I should mention that the Fortify scan results say that no files were excluded as the file pattern specified did not match any files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Additional Fortify SCA build options section, try this:

```
-exclude $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\UnitTests\ -exclude $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\**\UnitTests\
```

Use quotes if you have spaces in your sources directory. This should ignore the UnitTests folder in the root folder (if you have one), and any within sub-folders. I have found the last `\` works better than `\**`.

Reference: [SCA Guide 20.2](https://www.microfocus.com/documentation/fortify-static-code-analyzer-and-tools/2020/SCA_Guide_20.2.0.pdf) page 123 - Specifying Files and Directories

Comment: Sorry it took so long to get back to this, it worked!  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
-exclude "<dir>/**/UnitTests/**"
```

It matches all directories and files found in the named directory that have `UnitTests` in the path, including `UnitTests` as a file name. Also, on Windows, you can use the backslash character () as the directory separator instead of the forward slash (/).

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work.  The command is building based on a repository in ADO.  This is the command generated by the pipeline: sourceanalyzer.exe -b Build_83149.  That build number changes every time we run it.

Comment: @DZx: Usually, I `git clone` my C# code from ADO and use build integration with Fortify. This gives me better control over the commands being fired. My translation command goes like: `sourceanalyzer -b <buildID> -exclude <pattern> -logfile <logLocation> MSBuild.exe <MS Build Options> <Path to Solution(.sln) File>`. Works like a charm for me.

Comment: The build ID changes every time.  I need to see if I can pick that up as a variable, since this is supposed to run every time we do a production release.  Thanks for the info!

Comment: @DZx Check out the [Predefined Variables in a Azure Pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml). The `BuildID` or `BuildNumber` should be good to use.

Comment: @DZx, Were you able to resolve the issue? Can you post an answer to your question? It will help many others facing the same issue.